# Updating a variable inside the for loop is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variable-assignment, python-3.8

in this below code, I am trying to update **rsum** value to **(rsum - lsum - nums[i])** inside for loop, it's giving me the wrong output. But if I declare a new variable name and assign **(rsum - lsum - nums[i])** value to that, it gives me the right output. What's the reason behind this?

1. Code that gives wrong output

   ```
   def pivotIndex(nums: List[int]) -> int:
       n = len(nums)

       if n == 1: return 0

       lsum = 0
       rsum = sum(nums)

       for i in range(n):
           rsum = rsum - lsum - nums[i]
           if lsum == rsum:
               return i

           lsum += nums[i]

       return -1
   ```
2. Code that gives me the right output

   ```
   def pivotIndex(nums: List[int]) -> int:
       n = len(nums)

       if n == 1: return 0

       lsum = 0
       rsum = sum(nums)

       for i in range(n):
           total = rsum - lsum - nums[i]
           if lsum == total:
               return i

           lsum += nums[i]

       return -1
   ```

Comment: You could just add a load of print statements to see the value of total and rsum through each iteration? That usually helps me understand my code if I’m stuck.

Comment: The second time through your loop, `rsum` has the original value if your second solution and a new value in your first solution.  They are doing completely different things

Comment: If code 2 is correct then maybe code 1 should be: 'rsum = rsum - nums[i]'. This way you subtract just the current num from rsum each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 11 where you are getting the wrong output, you are changing rsum's value each so when you do (rsum-lsum-num[i]), you will get the new rsum value from which we'll remove lsum and num[i]. When you will be checking `lsum == rsum` it may be true once but than as rsum's value will have changed, it may not be equal.

On the code where you are getting the correct input, rsum will remain the same, which is `sum(nums)` and you will each time remove lsum and nums[i].

I don't know if I'm clear enough, and if I'm not, please tell me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and pointing out my silly mistake. I understood where I was wrong.